# Why my friend was able to facebook sign in to other people account

Tags: facebook, security, login

Recently, my friend show me that although she is using her own username and password, once a while, she will get accidentally sign in into a stranger account.

How can it be possible someone else cookie being transmitted to your computer?

I search some article : http://www.businessinsider.com/weird-att-glitch-allowed-users-to-access-other-peoples-facebook-account-2010-1

Some blame this issue to network service provider by using **routing problem** term.

Is it true?

If this really happen, isn't that the security will out of our developer control, by heavily depend on the network service provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some blame this issue to network service provider by using **routing problem** term.
>
> Is it true?

Yes, this is possible. A few years ago, an ISP in Australia was mixing up cookies for their subscribers. I don't recall if it was ever resolved, but the same type of thing could happen if the routers were incorrectly programmed.